# FFmpeg filter complex audio

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I add the aac to the filter_complex/split so the audio only is encoded once as the yadif?

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -i test.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif=1,split=2[out1][out2]" -map "[out1]" -s 1920:1080 -c:v h264_nvenc -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 4.5M -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 192k test2.mp4 -map "[out2]" -s 768:432 -c:v h264_nvenc -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 1.5M -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 192k test3.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video is being encoded twice which is unavoidable because you are outputting two different width x height. Your audio is the same for each output, so you can use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) to only encode audio once and put it in both outputs:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i test.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif=1,format=yuv420p,split=2[vid1][vid2];[vid1]scale=-2:1080[1080];[vid2]scale=-2:432[432]" -map "[1080]" -map "[432]" -map 0:a:0 -c:v h264_nvenc -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v:0 4.5M -b:v:1 1.5M -c:a aac -b:a 192k -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']1080.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\']432.mp4"
```

Comment: Worked fine,super thanks!